# PowerBI Desktop not refreshing data when SQL view is changed

Tags: powerbi

I am growing exceedingly frustrated with Power BI.  I have data being pulled into Power BI desktop from a view on Microsoft SQL Server.

I was able to make a connection to the view just fine, the problem is that when I alter the view and delete some of the existing columns and add new ones, Power BI is not recognizing this when I try and refresh the data.

Following the instructions I've found online, following the edits to the view in SQL I go to `"Edit Queries"` in PowerBI.  Then, I hit `"refresh data"`.  I get the error that for the field that has just been deleted in the SQL view, that `"the column of the table cannot be found"`

None of the new fields I've added in SQL are there either.

Is this a known bug with PowerBI?  Has it been documented?

I'm considering abandoning PowerBI since nearly every simple task I try to accomplish seems to be exceedingly difficult.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common issue I run into when I try to switch the name of the SQL table to something else. I did not think it would get impacted by a change in schema as well. Anyways, here is what I do when I run into this:

1. In the Edit query section, select the "settings" icon next to Source
2. Your source values will likely remain the same, Click "OK"
3. Then click the "settings" icon next to "Navigation" and select the corresponding view
4. This step usually refreshes your schema and other
   corresponding details
5. Once you do this, your error should be fixed

Hope this helps.

Comment: A permutation of this worked for me. I also needed to click on `Source` and then select the `Refresh Preview` -> `Refresh All` option.